# Any idea why my model is getting squished?

Tags: modeling, animation

It does this when i parent it to the bones with auto weights
or envelope

Before
[image]

After
[image]

Comment: your bones have weird proportions, perhaps select them all in Pose mode and press alt S

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27434/armature-deformations-squishing-solid-objects and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74072/parenting-mesh-with-armature-deformation-problem/74129#74129

Comment: turns out the bone constraint pole angle was messed up set it to zero and fixed it. Thank you!